# C++ Primer 5th Edition (Stanley) - Question on exercise 7-39

Tags: c++, c++11

Working through some exercises in C++ Primer 5th Ed (Stanley) and on exercise 7-39.

1. Class for exercise 7-39.

   ```
   class Sales_data {
   public:

   // defines the default constructor as well as one that takes a string argument
   Sales_data(std::string s = ""): bookNo(s) {}

   // remaining constructors unchanged
   Sales_data(std::string s, unsigned cnt, double rev): bookNo(s), units_sold(cnt), revenue(rev*cnt) {}

   Sales_data(std::istream &is) { read(is, *this); }

   // remaining members as before
   ```
2. Question:
   Exercise 7.39: Would it be legal for both the constructor that takes a
   string and the one that takes an istream& to have default arguments? If
   not, why not?
3. My answer:
   Yes. I can have the following:

   ```
    Sales_data(std::string s = ""): bookNo(s) {}
    Sales_data(std::istream &is = std::cin) { read(is, *this); }
   ```

The above are valid.
However there are some site with solution for this C++ Primer 5th edition which says no as below:

https://github.com/Mooophy/Cpp-Primer/tree/master/ch07 (you need to scroll down to exercise 7-39. Answer does not make sense)

https://github.com/jaege/Cpp-Primer-5th-Exercises/blob/master/ch7/7.39.md (this answer does not make sense at all)

I would like some other opinion if i am missing something. I still stand by my answer to far.

Thx

Comment: Which one would the compiler choose if one provides no arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make two default constructors, you effectively have no usable default constructor. If you try to default construct a `Sales_data` when you have more than one default constructor, there will be ambiguity and the program will fail to compile.

So, this is pointless

```
Sales_data(std::string s = "") : bookNo(s) {}
Sales_data(std::istream &is = std::cin) { read(is, *this); }
```

and better written like this:

```
Sales_data(std::string s) : bookNo(s) {}
Sales_data(std::istream &is) { read(is, *this); }
```

Comment: I think it is better to generalize the answer to ambiguous constructors. Because they may not be default constructors. For example if constructors were like `Sales_data(const std::string&, int i = 0)` and `Sales_data(const std::string&, const std::string& s = "")`, we cannot call them again with single string.

Comment: @Afshin One doesn't need to restrict it to _constructors_ either. This goes for any function.

Comment: true :) I meant same, just gave a sample.

Comment: Default argument are NOT parameters?

Comment: @yapkm01 A default value will be used by the selected construtor if the user of the class does not supply it. If you don't supply a value you have two constructors equally eligible to be used. It can only select one but there is not enough information for the compiler to select one - so there will be a compilation error.

Comment: i understand. Reason i am asking is had those default argument considered as parameter then there will be no issue such as ambiguity. That was why you written above that it would have been better to not have default value as in the 2nd examples of yours. So if i have foo(int x=1, int y) {} how many parameter does this foo has? I presume this will not be considered as default constructor since the int y does not have default argument

Comment: @yapkm01 Even if the declaration includes a default value, the number of arguments in the definition of the function is fixed, so that has 2 arguments, even if you supply one only.

Comment: Nevermind .. i think i understand now. Tx

Comment: @yapkm01 Great, you're welcome! There's a good description on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) too: "_A default constructor is a constructor which can be called with no arguments (either defined with an empty parameter list, **or with default arguments provided for every parameter**). A type with a public default constructor is DefaultConstructible._"

Answer (score 3):

Code can have more than one default constructor, and still be well formed.

But there's a bit of a trick to that: if you have more than one default constructor, you can't ever default-construct objects of that type, because the attempt at default construction would be ambiguous (i.e., the compiler wouldn't know which default constructor to use).

For example, consider something like this:

```cpp
class foo {
    int x;
public:
    foo() : x(1) {}
    foo(int x = 0) {}
};
```

By itself, that much is well-formed code (i.e., a properly functioning compiler should accept it--though it may well give a warning about it).

But if you try to default construct an object of that type:

```cpp
int main() { 
    foo f;
}
```

...*that* code is ill formed (i.e., a properly functioning compiler should reject it).

That said, most reasonably sane people looking at your code would generally consider this a bad idea. When somebody sees a constructor like `foo(int x=0)`, they tend to presume that the intent is that you can default-construct an object of that class. But if you have ambiguous constructors, you can't, so the code is basically lying.

**Summary**

At least from the compiler's viewpoint, creating code that *could* lead to ambiguity isn't necessarily a problem in itself. It's only when you try to *use* it in a way that triggers the ambiguity that your code is ill formed (and even then, it's the code that tries to *use* the ambiguous constructors that's ill-formed, not the code that creates the potential ambiguity).

Also note this isn't specific to constructors. Other overloaded functions are the same way. Two overloaded functions that provide default arguments for all parameters work out the same way--having the of them *exist* is allowed, but any code that attempts to invoke that overloaded function without an argument so it triggers the ambiguity is ill-formed.

Comment: In short default argument are NOT parameter, right?

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot have both. It would result in a compilation error `C2668: 'Sales_data::Sales_data': ambiguous call to overloaded function` when you try to construct the object without any argument, as the example shown below.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Sales_data { 
    public: 
    Sales_data(std::string s = "") {
        std::cout << "1st constructor"  << std::endl;
    } 
    Sales_data(std::string s, unsigned cnt, double rev) {
        std::cout << "2nd constructor"  << std::endl;
    } 
    Sales_data(std::istream &is = std::cin) {
        std::cout << "3rd constructor"  << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Sales_data s;  // The compiler would fail here. :)
    return 0;
}
```

Notice that the definition of `Sales_data s;` in the main function is ambiguous because the complier does not know if it should call `Sales_data(std::string s = "")` or `Sales_data(std::istream &is = std::cin)` to construct the object.